# Firefox Can't Print the Glossary of mathematical symbols of Wikipedia

Tags: firefox

Firefox can't print the Glossary of mathematical symbols - Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols

When using Firefox -> File -> Print, Firefox will try to print all pages but it will stop with the following error: Print Preview Error: An error occurred while printing.

**It's a BUG of Firefox 95.0 (64-bit).**

Comment: Filed [the bug on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1748077) for you. Happy new year :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I filed [a bug on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1748077) to capture this problem.

**Update**: this turned out to be a bug in the [Cairo library](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/-/issues/526) used by Firefox. This is being fixed upstream and is currently worked around in Firefox Nightly 97.0a1 (2022-01-08).